# Determining whether focus was received as result of a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an `<input>` element that can either have the focus set via code, or as the result of a mouse click.

If the user clicks on the input, then the `click` event handler will fire - all well and good. If the element receives the focus via some other way (e.g. via code) then I want to manually trigger the `click` event so that the handler will also fire.

I could do this:

```
$elem = $('input');
$elem
    .on('focus', function() { $(this).trigger('click') })
    .on('click', function() { alert('Clicked!') });
```

However, this will result in `click` handler being fired twice; once for the `click` event and once for the `focus` event.

Is there any way to selectively trigger the `click` handler only if the focus was *not* received as the result of a click event?

---

**UPDATE**

This is a very simplified version of my problem, so I can't do things like bind both handlers to the `focus` event etc. I'm trying to merge two third-party pieces of code.

Comment: Why don't you _just_ bind the events to the `focus` handler? I don't see why the `click` handler needs to be used.

Comment: When you click on a element, update a variable saying that you clicked. When the focus event is raised check if that variable is true, if not raise the click event else reset your variable

Comment: @ChristianVarga, this is a simplified version of my overall problem. I'm using third party code that is binding to the `click` event; there is also some other third party code that creates the `<input>` and sets the focus. I want to marry the two together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research it appears that there is no way of *guaranteeing* which event will fire first: `click` or `focus`. (There doesn't seem to be a standard that dictates the order of events.)

This means that when the `focus` event fires there's no way to determine if a `click` event will or will not be triggered by the browser shortly afterwards.

I managed to solve the issue by using `setTimeout()` to run a test about 100ms after the `focus` event fired to check if the `click` event had fired. The third-party code that I was using (bound to the `click` event) added an extra class to the `<input>`, so I was able to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function adds a property [`isTrigger`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ab409d14bc6db42b4af3ba753be1b55fe8f897d8/src/event.js#L255) in the event object to identify that the event was triggered by its usage. Although, it is not documented the property is still present in jQuery 1.8.3 but it seems to only be used internally.

Anyways, you can make use of the `extraParameters` parameter to add a custom property to the event object. For instance,

```
$(this).trigger('click', {
    isTrigger: true
});
```

It will keep the compatibility with `isTrigger` even if it is gone in a future release.

Comment: Excellent suggestion; I thought this was going to solve my problem. Unfortunately, after thinking about it, the issue isn't whether the `click` event was triggered by a `focus` event, but whether the `focus` event is accompanied by a `click` event. I need to decide *beforehand* whether or not to trigger the `click`.

Comment: For what this question is concerned I believe it is answered. You may want to stop "simplifying" your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the `mousedown` event which fires before the `focus` event.  When you click a focusable object the order of events is as follows...  `mousedown`, `focus`, `mouseup`, `click`.

You could set a flag in the `mousedown` event and then check for it in the `focus` event to see if the focus came from a mouse click. Obviously make sure to clear the flag in the `focus` event handler.  Every application is different, but tapping into the `mousedown` event allows you to figure out a solution.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the order of events... http://jsfiddle.net/ek7v7/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had one behavior on the `focus` and another on the `click` event.
I changed to the `mousedown` event and did work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$elem = $('input');
$elem
    .on('focus', function() { alert("Focused!") })
```

Focus can be fired by focusing the input by using tab, clicking it, or by using .focus()

Is there a reason for on('click', ...)?

Comment: Please see my comment to the original question. This is a simplified version of my problem and I want to marry the two events together.